# In magento language translation is not working

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I need inline language translate in magento but it's not working.

I want to translate custom content, which is added from product tab at admin side and displayed at front-end.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First locate the template being loaded:

1. Go to `System->Configuration->Advanced->Developer`, select your store view in the dropdown on the top-left, expand the `Debug` section, and set all 3 options to `Yes`
2. Load the content in question on the frontend. There will be a red border around the area with the text you want translated, and you should also see the path to the template being loaded.

Then edit the template file. Try this:

```
echo $this->__("I Need To Translate This Text");
```

The `__()` method is a text translator method that belongs to the Helper_Abstract that all helpers extend from.

This will make translations based on CSV file in:

```
/path/to/magento/app/locale/
```

Comment: i am follow below for translate in magento,
echo $this->__('test');
but i want to use follow,
echo $this->__($str);
is this possible in magento?
in $str i have more then one words.
i have already .csv for translate its.
like 
Label:   Contents:
Name     ABC

Answer (score 1):

If you want to translate name of the product from inline translation, see in phtml file if that is echoed under `$this->__("")`